# Wiring Considerations for numerous LED's

Tags: power-supply, led, wiring

I'm working on a hobby project where I'm going to need to wire up 40-80 (not sure exactly how many yet) LED's of various colors. Only 10-20 of them are going to be on at a time. This is going to be a hobby project and I'm by no means an electrician so I don't have the knowledge/skill or need for a highly technical highly redundant solution. This project is a prop; it's not small but it's not very big either so space is going to be a consideration. There are going to be 4 sets of LED's and only one set can be on at a time. Currently my plan is to use an Arduino board and some transistors along with a battery back from a RC car/helicopter/etc to power the LED's and insure that only one set is on at a time. Now for the questions:

What considerations are there as far as wiring the groups of LED's up in Series vs Parallel? Being a small scale hobby project does it really make a difference either way?

I read in another post on the site about a similar topic that it was recommended to use a current limiter. Is that something I should consider as well? As I said the power source will most likely be a battery pack from a hobby RC (LiPo or whatever they are currently making them out of). Are those consistent or will there be enough variation in the voltage/current that I need to find a way to mitigate the differences?

If you have any other things I really need to consider for this project please feel free to note them so I can do some research.

Please note when you respond that I'm not going to understand complex electrical diagrams or formulas. If the answer is pretty complex you might need to just point me in the direction of some reference material and let me research it. Also if you suggest using current limiters or any other specific pieces of equipment a link to any electrical website's part page for one of them would be appreciated. That will help me confirm I'm looking for the right thing when I get around to buying one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you say you don't want a highly technical solution, then I suggest you simply buy a ready made LED strip. This way you don't have to worry about current limiting (which is absolutely needed), it's done for you.

[eBay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_trksid=p4634.m570.l1313&_nkw=led%20strip&_sacat=0) sell thousands of these, but probably the best place to get them is Adafruit - their [RGB Strips](http://www.adafruit.com/products/285) are likely to be half decent (they sell other versions too, have a browse), and they have a good [tutorial](http://www.ladyada.net/products/rgbledstrip/) on using them.

[image: RGB Strip]
[image: RGB Blue] [image: RGB Green]

**Wiring Diagram**

Below is an example of wiring (from the tutorial above) using an N-Channel power MOSFET such as the [STP16NF06](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00002501.pdf) (gate pin 1, drain pin2, source pin 3):

[image: Wiring example]

Comment: The problem with this suggestion is that I need to have specific colors and I need to be able to place the LED's exactly where I want them. They are being used to illuminate recesses in the prop. I guess I need to do some more research and learn about current limiting.

Comment: You can have specific colours with these strips, with RGB you can produce any colour you wish to (like a pixel) Alternatively, if the colour never has to change, pick a strip with LEDs of the desired colour. You can also cut these strips to any length you wish, so placement is not an issue.

Comment: Ok well I'll definitely consider it. I think the individual LED's I have selected will give me more versatility even if they are a pain to wire up. My biggest concern with this solution is that the LED's need to be concealed and I don't know if I'd be able to do that with the strip. I may need to get one and test it to see if I can hide it like I need to.